# Running AWS services in bash script creates an error when trying to run the second command, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

So I have a bash script that runs some AWS commands to spin up an ECS service, I then want to attach some autoscaling policies to it but I am getting an error. I'm not sure if it is anything to do with the AWS service CLI or I am running it incorrectly in bash, syntax wise it seems fine according to the AWS docs.

Here's the code:

```
aws ecs create-service \
      --cluster $1 \
      --service-name $2 \
      --task-definition $3:$4 \
      --desired-count $DESIRED_COUNT \
      --launch-type FARGATE \
      --platform-version LATEST \
      --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[${SUBNETS[0]}${SUBNETS[1]}${SUBNETS[2]}],securityGroups=[$SECURITY_GROUPS],assignPublicIp=ENABLED}" \
      --service-registries registryArn=$SERVICE_DISCOVERY_ARN \
      --load-balancers targetGroupArn=$BACKEND_TARGETGROUP,containerName=$BACKEND_CONTAINERNAME,containerPort=$BACKEND_CONTAINERPORT \
      --profile $PROFILE

    echo "============ Now creating $2 service auto-scaling policies ============"
    aws application-autoscaling register-scalable-target \
      --service-namespace ecs \
      --scalable-dimension ecs:service:DesiredCount \
      --resource-id "service/$CLUSTER/$BACKEND_SERVICE" \
      --min-capacity $MINIMUM_APP_COUNT --max-capacity $MAXIMUM_APP_COUNT
    
    aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy 
      --service-namespace ecs \
      --scalable-dimension ecs:service:DesiredCount \
      --resource-id "service/$CLUSTER/$BACKEND_SERVICE" \
      --policy-name "${CLUSTER}_scale_up" --policy-type StepScaling \
      --step-scaling-policy-configuration file://stepScalingUpPolicy.json
    
    aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy 
      --service-namespace ecs \
      --scalable-dimension ecs:service:DesiredCount \
      --resource-id "service/$CLUSTER/$BACKEND_SERVICE" \
      --policy-name "${CLUSTER}_scale_down" --policy-type StepScaling \
      --step-scaling-policy-configuration file://stepScalingDownPolicy.json
```

Image is of error on my pipeline after running the first aws service.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PxBW.png

Comment: I've noticed that you have a number of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. If all of them were not good, then that's fine. But if they were helpful, acceptance is not only a good practice, but it also removes your question for unanswered list and reduces number of duplicate questions.

Comment: Still bit of a fresh user to SO, will take a look and adjust.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing slashes `\` after two commands. It should be

```
 aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy \
```

and

```
aws application-autoscaling put-scaling-policy \
```

Also make sure you don't have any white characters (spaces or tabs) after `\\`.

Comment: yeah I understand this, I actually didn't have this due to the AWS doc not needing it, however having a look at something else; the answer may be this:

aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy --policy-name alb1000-target-tracking-scaling-policy \

Comment: adding the policy name after the service declaration may be the answer, will let you know the outcome - will also check for extra spaces.

Comment: @narliecholler No problem, but you still should have slashes, just like in your first two commands.

Comment: I assume it is okay to chain AWS commands one after the other and there is no need for an additional command that 'ends' the previous one?

Comment: @narliecholler your are missing slash at the begging of commands, after first line like I wrote in the answer. This is about multi-line breaking commands, not about chaining them.

Comment: @narliecholler How did it go? The issue persists?

Comment: Have yet to try this, currently working through some other Terraform issues in our pipeline before getting to this script as a separate problem. Will let you know when we do get around to trying this. Cheers.

Comment: I can confirm it now works, I also had error with it finding local files to configure scaling configuration but I changed that to it being inline. Thanks.

Comment: the command runs successfully - however in the AWS environment, no policies are getting added to the ECS tasks, do you have any thoughts as to why? All variables are correct.

Comment: @narliecholler It seems like a new issue, so new question would be better.